# as3 - Can you get a reference to the element in a for...each...in loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, iteration

Actionscript provides the loop **for...in** to reference the element being iterated, through the key.

But the **for...each...in** loop yields a copy of the element rather a reference to the original element in the collection being iterated. Is there a way to get a reference to it or do I have to resort to **for...in**?

Consider the *hypothetical*:

```
for each( var &iter:* in collection )
```

I know there is no such dereferencing operator in actionscript, but can you get a reference here by any other means?

**PS**: [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for_each..in) states that:

> variableIterant:* — The name of a variable to act as the iterant, *referencing* the item in a collection.

Although it's rather a copy by value and not a reference.

Answer (score 5):

> But the for...each...in loop yields a copy of the element rather a
>   reference to the original element in the collection being iterated.

Uhh... No it doesn't. Otherwise this test would yield `0 0`:

```
var a:Shape = new Shape();
var b:Shape = new Shape();
var list:Array = [a,b];

for each(var i:Shape in list) i.x = 10;

trace(a.x, b.x); // 10 10
```